# Understanding the mechanism of adding contacts without accounts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

According to official documentation:

> The Contacts Provider combines the raw contact rows across all account
>   types and account names to form a contact.

But what if a contact which is added to the user's device is added with only a mobile phone number and its owner not binding it to some of user's accounts? How does it added to the contacts and does it have any 'raw contact' record in `ContactsContract.RawContacts` table?